# Turn subversion path into walkable directory

Tags: python

I have a subversion repo ie "http://crsvn/trunk/foo" ... I want to walk this directory or for starters simply to a directory list.

The idea is to create a script that will do mergeinfo on all the branches in "http://crsvn/branches/bar" and compare them to trunk to see if the branch has been merged.

So the first problem I have is that I cannot walk or do

```
os.listdir('http://crsvn/branches/bar')
```

I get the value label syntax is incorrect (mentioning the URL)

Comment: Found a solution that works: Used pysvn module and used 'list' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PySVN](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn.html). In particular, the [pysvn.Client.list](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_list) method should do what you want:

```
import pysvn
svncl = pysvn.Client()
entries = svncl.list("http://rabbitvcs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/")
# Gives you a list of directories:
dirs = (entry[0].repos_path for entry in entries if entry[0].kind == pysvn.node_kind.dir)
list(dirs)
```

No checkout needed. You could even specify a revision to work on, to ensure your script can ignore other people working on the repository while it runs.

Answer (score 0):

[`listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) takes a path and not a url.  It would be nice if python could be aware of the structure on a remote server but i don't think that is the case.

If you were to checkout your repository locally first you could easly walk the directories using pythons functions.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that this is the problem. I am not sure how to fix it. I could check it out, however, we're talking a large number of large repos and I would probably run out of harddrive space :)